# How do I get all the 'managerzone' from the project or 'record' from the 'managerzone' using the Google Cloud DNS API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dns

I want to get all the 'managerzone' using the API. I call the method to get the project, but in the response I do not receive information about all the 'managerzone' that are in this project. There is a similar problem with getting 'record' in managerzone. How can I get all the records that are in the 'managerzone'?

link to the document

- https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/reference/v1/projects/get
- https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/reference/v1beta2/managedZones/get

Comment: Edit your question. Include your code and response(s) received from the API.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the only way to list managed zones is by running this command on the gcp console:

```
gcloud dns managed-zones list
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dns/managed-zones/list